# Why is client-side hashing of a password so uncommon?

Tags: authentication, passwords, hash, password-cracking, account-security

There are very few websites that hash the users password before submitting it to the server. Javascript doesn't even have support for SHA or other algorithms.

But I can think of quite a few advantages, like protection against cross-site leaks or malicious admins, which SSL does not provide.

So why is this practise so uncommon among websites?

Comment: What advantages do you think there are to client side hashing of passwords?

Comment: @TimLamballais A typical client can spend far more time on hashing than a server. So if you have a high performance implementation in the client (which rules out javascript in current browsers) you can use more expensive and thus stronger password hashes. It also means that the server never sees the password itself. Client side hashing is also a prerequisite for augmented PAKE protocols like SRP where impersonating the server doesn't give you access to the password.

Comment: Javascript isn't really that slow anymore. Modern javascript engines have become so fast that they are on-par with compiled languages and recent additions like typed arrays provide the proper tools for the number-crunching required for cryptography.

Comment: @TimLamballais One advantage would be that the server never sees my real password, and cannot possibly leak it (yes, they can still leak the hash, but it should be salted by the domainname, so useless for login to other sites). But for the largest advantage see my comment to Phillip's answer.

Comment: A lot of people question whether any extra security is gained with this practice. One thing it does do is reduce risk. If you always hash or encrypt (I've seen steam/valve encrypt with a public key and I bet they are not decrypting) there is no chance of you ever having an embarrassing plaintext breech. No...it isn't any more secure but it isn't pointless

Comment: WPA2-PSK uses client-side hashing of password for authentication.

Comment: Update -- for native support of slow-hashing in common browsers, see github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/59

Comment: So I enter my password, a malicious agent interferes with the hash, and now neither I nor the server know my password!

Answer (score 77, accepted):

**Inventor of JavaScript password hashing here**

Way back in 1998 I was building a Wiki, the first web site I'd built with a login system. There was no way I could afford hosting with SSL, but I was concerned about plaintext passwords going over the Internet. I'd read about CHAP (challenge hash authentication protocol) and realised I could implement it in JavaScript. I ended up publishing [JavaScript MD5](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/) as a standalone project and it has become the most popular open source I've developed. The wiki never got beyond alpha.

Compared to SSL it has a number of weaknesses:

- Only protects against passive eavesdropping. An active MITM can tamper with the JavaScript and disable hashing.
- Server-side hashes become password equivalents. At least in the common implementation; there are variations that avoid this.
- Captured hashes can be brute forced. It is theoretically possible to avoid this using JavaScript RSA.

I've always stated these limitations up front. I used to periodically get flamed for them. But I maintain the original principle to this day: If you've not got SSL for whatever reason, this is better than plaintext passwords. In the early 2000s a number of large providers (most notably Yahoo!) used this for logins. They believed that SSL even just for logins would have too much overhead. I think they switched to SSL just for logins in 2006, and around 2011 when Firesheep was released, most providers switched to full SSL.

So the short answer is: **Client-side hashing is rare because people use SSL instead.**

There are still some potential benefits of client-side hashing:

- Some software doesn't know if it will be deployed with SSL or not, so it makes some sense to include hashing. vBulletin was a common example of this.
- Server relief - with computationally expensive hashes, it makes sense for the client to do some of the work. See [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58704/can-client-side-hashing-reduce-the-denial-of-service-risk-with-slow-hashes).
- Malicious admins or compromised server - client-side hashing can prevent them from seeing plaintext passwords. This is usually dismissed because they could modify the JavaScript and disable hashing. But in fairness, that action increases their chances of being detected, so there is some merit to this.

Ultimately though these benefits are minor, and add a lot of complexity - there's a real risk that you'll introduce a more serious vulnerability in your attempt to improve security. And for people who want more security than password, multi-factor authentication is a better solution.

So the second short answer is: **because multi-factor authentication provides more security than client-side password hashing.**

Comment: What if, _the server has been compromised_ by a cracker and he'd like to gather plain passwords from clients to use them at other places? No safeguard but client-side hashing. Why must we force clients to trust the server?

Comment: @КонстантинВан - please refer to the "compromised server" part of the answer

Comment: Another drawback of client side hashing is that you cannot enforce password policy on the server. Basically you cannot validate that the user selected password is strong enough

Comment: @Michael That's a good thing in my opinion, since password policies on most servers are ridiculous. Many password characters are forbidden for no reason.

Comment: Clientside-salted hashing completely ELIMINATES the need for any for password policies. THIS IS WHY IT SHOULD BE DONE.

Comment: @Константин Ван If the server is compromised then no password scheme is effective. What is your point? At least in this scenario, a database bruteforce becomes impossible.

Comment: @Tomáš Zato THIS IS THE ANSWER I CAME HERE TO SEE. LOCALLY HASH PASSWORDS, KILL STUPID PASSWORD POLICIES.

Comment: @8vtwo The point is: _if a user has a client that hashes_ (with a salt) his plaintext password prior to sending it to the server, the compromised server cannot keep it and use it to sign in to other services; because plaintext passwords are not sent. Well, yes; for web services, it could be pointless as the server can alter and redistribute the code running on the client side. The pros of the client-side hashing is only for services where an update to client code is in control of the user; like client executables, not web services.

Comment: @Константин Ван This makes no sense. 1. If site is compromised, its use of the webservice is compromised as well so there is no difference or benefit 2. You are just moving the hack down the line, now the "webservice" has to be hacked for there to be damage? You aren't making ANY SENSE.

Comment: @8vtwo 1. By "compromised," I mean the attacker seizing the server and _having it pretend to be normally functional._ 2. By "web service," I mean the server and client; that are on the web, where the server can alter the code on the client side any time it wants (where the client loads its code from the server.). 3. I hope that makes sense to you now.

Comment: @@Константин Ван You didn't clarify anything I didn't already know. FACT: There are NO KNOWN DISADVANTAGES to client-side hashing ALONG WITH serverside hashing. There are ONLY ADVANTAGES. IF YOU DISAGREE PLEASE STATE REASONING.

Comment: Now I see. Listen, @8vtwo, I wasn’t talking about why you shouldn’t do client-side password hashing. Chill and tone down a bit. I’ve been here for it, not against it.

Comment: @Michael Client-side hashing does ***NOT*** "eliminate" server-side password requirements/policy validation. The server *still* has to run the entire password hashing algorithm *over the raw unhashed client password* once during (1) new account registration and (2) during password resets. Of course these happen **far more rarely** than plain/basic/standard login anyway, so you can still gain quite some server-relief by doing the slow-hashing on the client-side (along with, of course, a quick hash on the server too) as well.

Answer (score 58):

To understand this problem, first you have to understand why we hash passwords.  It is completely possible to store a password in plain text on a server and simply compare the password transmitted to the password received.  As long as the password is protected in transit, this is a secure means of authentication (shared secret).

The reason that passwords are hashed is because the problem isn't the authentication, but the storage.  If the server is ever compromised, the attacker would immediately have access to all user accounts as they would now know the secret used for authentication of the users.

Hashing acts as a barrier to this.  Since the server doesn't know the actual input required to authenticate, even a compromise to the DB does not grant an attacker access to the user accounts.  They would still need to figure out the input to give to reach the hash values the application checks against.  Sure they could alter all the values to something they know, but this would rapidly throw up suspicion and the system would be shut down and secured.

So, the problem with client side hashing is that it effectively makes the result of the hash the password rather than the password.  There is nothing to stop an attacker from bypassing the official client and simply sending the finished hash to the server directly.  It provides no additional (or loss) of security during the authentication, but under the situation that hashing is designed to protect against, it offers nothing since the hash stored in the DB is actually the shared secret transmitted to the server.

That said, there are two notable thing client side hashing does give you.  While it doesn't help protect your system at all, it may help protect your user.  If you are insecurely transmitting the password or the transmission gets compromised without the client code getting compromised, you will still protect the user's password (which they may reuse on other sites) from being leaked.

The other is that you can provide additional iterations of a hash to make an offline attack against the DB more difficult (or near impossible if the hash output is long enough) without having to use server cycles (effectively extending the length of the "intermediate" password that the client submits), but you still need sufficient server cycles to protect the lengthened password against a rogue client.  It's still pretty limited in how many effective characters it adds.  According to the math I did, a 1 second slow hash, even implemented efficiently by the browser in native code such that nobody could hash it faster than that, would only add about 6 random characters of entropy to the password, and getting 7 characters of entropy would require about a 100 second slow hash.

Put another way, while it does provide some protections, from the point of view of the server, the client side hash should be treated as if it was the user's direct password.  **It provides no more or no less security *on the server* than if the user had directly given their password and should be protected as such.**

If you want to be able to provide that extra level of security, I would recommend two hashes.  Hash once client side to build a new, unique password, then hash that password on the server to make a value you store in the DB.  This way you get the best of both worlds.

For the most part, SSL is trusted sufficiently to protect the exchange that the initial hash prior to transmission is seen as unnecessary though and a compromised server could always alter the code sent to the client such that the initial hash isn't performed.  It simply isn't an effective alternative to SSL and doesn't offer enough additional advantage to be worth the costs and complexity.

Comment: I need to encrypt some data client-side, and by sending only the hash to the server, I can proof that the server cannot decrypt the local data, since it doesn't know the plain-text password. Also, when salting the hash with the domainname, there is a garantuee that the server can never leak my password, just a salted (useless) hash.

Comment: @Muis my point is that the salted hash isn't useless.  It can compromise the integrity of your authentication system as it is the new password for authentication (even if not for encryption).  The attacker could still get the hash from the DB on the server and convince the server that they are the user and access the encrypted copy of the files (which granted, they may have access to already anyway at that point).  Additionally, a salt should be globally unique, not a domain name.

Comment: @Muis - my point is simply that you should treat the hash generated client side as if it was the user's own password when dealing with it server side.  It isn't bad to use a client side hash to protect the user's password from being exposed to the server, but it practically acts like the user's direct password as far as the server is concerned.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147258/discussion-on-answer-by-aj-henderson-why-is-client-side-hashing-of-a-password-so); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 23):

If you have quite a few advantages, then you should list them in your question so that people will find out whether they are truly useful (and you may become famous if so ;)

People don't favor client-side hashing because they have better ways of protecting users private information. Let's think about the places with potential information leaks and there are three of them:

- The client.
- Between the client and the server.
- The server.

Then let's see why or why not client-side hashing will help in these places.

- The client.

  If there are malwares on your own computer, for example, if your browser is compromised or your computer is implanted with key-logging software, client-side hashing doesn't prevent a hacker from getting your password. The reason is obvious.
- Between the client and the server.

  There is the communication channel between client and server. If there is an eavesdropper listening for the communication, then client-side hashing can make the leak of password more difficult because the eavesdropper has to recover the original password from its hash. It's indeed useful here.

  However, this vulnerability is based on the presupposition of an insecure communication channel. In reality, there are protocols whose existence tries to solve this problem exactly. Their major task is to establish a secure channel over an insecure one. The most famous and widely deployed example is SSL/TLS, and it provides more functionality and better security than client-side hashing.

  The conclusion is that client-side hashing is helpful in the channel, but here are better tools.
- The server.

  Users information may be leaked on the server if the server is compromised by a hacker. The hacker can fetch user passwords from database if they are stored in plaintext. That's why today most servers don't do that. Instead, they store hashes of passwords so that hackers can't easily restore the original passwords from their information at hand (i.e. hashes).

  You may be tempted to believe things still work well if the server simply stores hashes computed on the client side. But this is severely wrong. In that situation the hashes themselves become password equivalents. The hacker can pass authentication by simply handing over the hash without reversing it. The goal of a hacker is not reversing a hash, but breaking into your account. The importance lies in the server's verification process on client data, not on the fact that the data is a hash value. Therefore the benefit of *client-side* hashing is trivial here and the server must rehash anyway.

To summarize, client-side hashing is helpful in protecting user information, but the protection largely applies to the communication channel. Since we have better approaches there (SSL/TLS), the application of client-side hashing is greatly surpressed. It's simply not the best tool for the task at hand.

Comment: Re: this statement: "The goal of a hacker is not reversing a hash, but breaking into your account." I would say that depends on what the site is. Oftentimes the user's password is more valuable than access to the site, with the hopes that the password may be used on other sites where gaining access would have more value.

Comment: @TTT From its context, this sentence actually means the hacker doesn't care about whether it's a hash or a plaintext password as long as he gets the private information he wants.

Comment: This answer is super helpful.

Comment: I agree with TTT. I disagree that it is "better" (as you've said) for the client to send their password in plaintext instead of a salted hash.  This opens up the risk that some server-side agent steals or leaks the client password, either by malicious intent or negligence.  Since many users re-use password cross-side, it's a very concerning risk.

Comment: So the summary of your answer is "because I see only slight advantages"? Not because there are any disadvantages of doing only a fast hash on the server and the slow hash on the client? I elaborated a little on the topic in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/201099/10863) and am curious to hear your thoughts.

Comment: @Luc The idea is that the server uses whatever passed by the client as proof of identify, whether it's a hash or not. The server simply views it as a plain string and the server must do its own job to protect this string from being recovered by the malicious. If the client feels it needs to protect its password against a malicious server or vulnerable communication channel, then it is free to do so. But that's not the web server's job. For example, the client can use a random password for each site and no hashing is needed.

Comment: @Cyker Yep, if everyone would use a password manager with unique, random passwords, we would not have to have this discussion! But that's just not the case, we all know how frequently sites get hacked and that the data is used to hack the users on other sites, where they re-used their password. It's indeed not your job to protect the user, but neither is it your job to fix water in Africa. Still, countries that can afford it pay development aid (and in democratic countries, people collectively agree on it). We help other people where we can, so if we can just hash in a better spot, why not?

Comment: @Luc For *hash in a better spot*: What makes you think hashing on the client side is better than on the server side if the channel is secure? If you are using plain HTTP then you should move to HTTPS instead of relying on your own client-side hashing.

Comment: @Cyker See the link I posted earlier: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/201099/10863 There are lots of advantages to client-side hashing, all of which assume the transport channel is secure (you just reminded me that I forgot to mention the case where the transport channel is compromised!). Full agree on that https is much more important than client-side hashing, by the way. If you don't have https, there are way bigger issues.

Comment: @Luc Well if you think client side hashing is helpful in your specific use case, then you are free to implement it. Provided you are using a sane hashing algorithm, I don't see how it becomes harmful except wasting some resources on the client machine. For example, if you think the client machine is more secure than the server machine because there are some sour employees intercepting user data on the server side. Don't forget to salt the hash in that case.

Comment: @Cyker Salting, yes, thanks for reminding me to add that. People should indeed not forget to do that.

Comment: NOBODY IS SUGGESTING THE SERVER STOP HASHING PASSWORDS. ALL YOUR OTHER POINTS ARE FRIVOLOUS. CLIENT SIDE HASHING PROTECTED STORED PASSWORDS AND REMOVED PASSWORD POLICIES.

Answer (score 7):

It is good practice to hash on the client side, then salt the password and hash again on the server side.  This is an extra layer of protection against man in the middle attacks.  SSL is the first layer however Snowden's revelations made it clear that SSL can be compromised by organisations such as the NSA with relative ease.

Comment: This answer provides nothing that the other answers don't, and misses the point that to a MitM, the client's hash of the password can be used as if it were the password itself.

Comment: @Mark Um no Mark. This does indeed help with mitm. Mayhem is stating at hashing the hashed password yet again.

Comment: @Karl, The 'man in the middle' would still be providing the same request parameters as the target user.  Just because it isn't a password, doesn't mean the attacker can't intercept the hash and provide that same hash on to the server (to let it "hash the hash" and succeed at a match).

Comment: @RedGlobe That however is true. But it does help, because a looot of internet users use the same password for everything. I agree it might not help against that particular system, but it will help on a broader scale.

Answer (score 6):

What advantages would client-sided password hashing have?

Well, the password wouldn't be sent over the net in clear-text. But you should really be using TLS encryption when you log in, so password sniffing should not be an issue.

Another reason could be that you don't want the server to *ever* be aware of the users password, not even for a microsecond. That means you give the server the password hash on registration and then log in using that password hash. Unfortunately this doesn't solve anything: The shared secret to log into the account is now the hash, not the password. When you obtain knowledge of the hash, you can log in without knowing the actual password (because the server doesn't know it either).

Comment: The advantage for me would be that I can use the user's password to encrypt some local data in my app, and proof that the server is never able to decrypt that data (since it only knows the hash). Otherwise I would have two prompt the end-user for two different passwords (1 for login, 1 for encryption).

Comment: @Muis In that case the answer would be "Because nobody has such exotic requirements like you do".

Comment: @Muis, your definition of "proof" must be weak as often knowledge of the hash is equivalent to knowledge of the password since dictionary attacks are so successful. I do see your point though. It is proof if the user picks a good password.

Comment: @mikeazo I salt the hash, so dictionary attacks are useless.

Comment: @Muis That's not how salting works. Salts only protect against precomputed rainbow tables, not against dictionary attacks.

Comment: @Philipp, salt does guard against dictionary attacks where the attacker just wants one out of many captured hashes. It does not help against dictionary attacks on a single hash.

Comment: @muis in that case use a private symmetric key that is password protected.  This will generally provide far better security for the encrypted data due to the higher entropy of the symmetric key while also ensuring that the server does not have the ability to decrypt (as it does not have the private key).  Don't roll your own... use established and known secure patterns.

Comment: @Muis Using user password to encrypt local data may not be as good as you think. What happens if the user changes it's password? Also, if the server has the data to encrypt it with the user password, then the server doesn't need to decrypt the data, it already has it, so you can't proof that the server is unable to access the data (Which is the point of decrypting it)

Comment: -1 very short-sighted answer. Sure, what you transmit to the server is equivalent to your password. That is always the case. But it protects the user a lot better to hash it before transmission (TLS has its share of issues) and especially before it arrives on the server (where the real vulnerabilities usually happen).

Answer (score 4):

Since you are talking about web application...

In a database we have a table call dbo.useracc we are storing these hashes password

```
User        Password
--------       ----------
user1       5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
user2       202cb962ac59075b964b07152d234b70
user3       098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6
```

and our login function in web application be something like

```
if (user == $user and password == $pass) {
           return auth.token
}
```

Let's say an attacker successfully hacked and stole the database and saved our dbo.useracc data. He now has our hashed password.

If your login hashes process is stored in the client, the attacker can still accesses your account with the hashed password by just hooking up the HTTP POST method altering the password field to send your hashed password and he is still able to login. Remember your application data are communicating with the server through the POST method eventually after it's hashed to be checked against.

However if the hashing process is in the server, it's another story.

```
$pass = md5.hash($pass);

if (user == $user and password == $pass) {
           return auth.token;
}
```

If the hacker use the hashed password to login, it will be a hash 'hashed password' checking against a hashed password.

In this case let's say the attacker post

$user = user1
$pass = 5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99

After the server side doing $pass = md5.hash(5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99) it will return '696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3' which is returning a false statement.

This is to fence off attacker who has successfully stolen the database data and trying to access through the web application using the hashed password. And of course the attacker still can hack into the accounts if they successfully bruteforce / crack the hashes through dictionary attacks and so. However the hacker requires longer time if the password is a good password after compromising the system and the server admin could just reset the password and email the users.

Also it is also used to internal threats like employees in an enterprise. In an enterprise, there will be Database Administrator and Developers. They are different roles. Now to prevent the employee users to access to the sensitive data, they need to have access to both application and DB to get access to the data. Of course you might argue a DBA can still alter the database data through the database itself, but it is not accessible by the developers and it is easier to pinpoint where is the attack from. It is about access control rights and minimizing the risks and threats.

Comment: You're correct that it doesnt make it harder for an attacker to enter MY site using the stolen hash, but it makes it harder to login to ANOTHER site, since the other site most likely dont use exactly the same salt + hashing algorithm.

Comment: There's no way the attacker can access ANOTHER site with the hashed password too as long as the ANOTHER website don't practice hashing in the client and is a good password that is hard to be bruteforce by dictionary or rainbow table attacks. And as a developer, why would you even care about "ANOTHER" site in the first place. If the users value their other data a lot, they should practice not to use a global password instead.

Answer (score 3):

Though the topic has some concrete leak points, as pointed out by @Cyker, the discussion is a little brisk here ... I'd like to add one point that I didn't see mentioned.

It's simply that if you hash ASAP, then you reduce the programming risks of accidentally passing a clear text password somewhere that it shouldn't go. We already take measures like secure strings and secure arrays to try to destroy the clear text ASAP; and hashing at the moment that you get the password is another measure like that ... As code evolves, etc. the risks seem to still be reduced.

I just wrote a little C# "Box" that takes the SecureString clear text and hashes it immediately --- this way I simply know that it will never be logged or passed to a library I don't expect. This is not so much about a protocol as it is just the programmer here sitting and looking at a password --- I don't wan't to touch it! (It's still a password equivalent in some aspects, but it is at least immediately concealed from folly like moving a closing parenthesis in a chained method call and passing clear text to the wrong place. And a secure array is still not concealed.)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that if SSL/TLS is available the advantage of client-side hashing to protect the authentication process is limited. 
However, SSL / TLS does not resolve the vulnerability to custom hardware attacks if the attacker has access to the stored hashes (AFTER the process). Functions such as simple salted hashes or schemes like PBKDF2 are very vulnerable to these attacks because of their low memory requirements. The cracking of passwords, protected with theses schemes is cheap and fast. And that is at least one of the main problems of password hashing.

At first glance, this has nothing to do with client-side hashing versus SSL/TLS - but: 
When a sever implements a memory-hard password hashing scheme such as Scrypt, Argon2 or Catena to protect custom hardware attacks, the server‘s hardware requirements increase dramatically. In reality, services therefore reduce the memory-hardness or switch to vulnerable schemes. Client-side hashing helps a bit to get around this problem. When the clients compute these expensive (memory hard) functions, the service can use them without the need for better hardware.

Modern password hashing schemes therefore offer the possibility to delegate the most expensive (memory-hard) parts of the function to the client. This feature is called *server relief* and is offered by Argon2 and Catena.

Conclusion: Using modern password hashing schemes, which are much less vulnerable to custom hardware attacks, will increase or at least should increase the use of client-side hashing in the future  –  of course along with SSL/TLS.

Answer (score 2):

Most websites send the password as plain, or base-64 encoding (basic auth), and rely on the TLS layer for hiding the password. This is common practice, and is as safe as the TLS layer is really secured.

But TLS is not perfect either. In practice, most corporations include an **Interception Proxy** in their security chain. They added their own root CA to the corporate client devices, and actually intercept outgoing TLS requests, for security or regulatory reasons (e.g. log, monitoring). So the password is plain not only on the client and server side, but also at the interception proxy level.

We should therefore not rely on TLS for truly hiding sensitive information. Client side hashing seems mandatory if you expect a truly secure use of your secret password.

In addition to plain password hash, you may consider for additional security, and to avoid replay attacks:

- To include a *server-side challenge*: server sends random A, client hashes A + password and sends this value;
- To include *server-side and client-side challenges*: server sends random A, client computes random B, client hashes A + B + password and sends both B + hash;
- To include a *client-side puzzle* (blockchain-like proof): server sends random A, client loops computing some random B and hashing A + B + password until the hash starts with n zeros (the bigger the more computer intensive), client sends B and it is easy and cheap for the server to verify B.

Proven protocols always include client-side and server-side challenges, to avoid replay attacks. Hashing and challenging is uncommon on WebSites because:

- *Client-side hashing is slow* if done in plain JavaScript, so the most sophisticated proven means like client-side puzzle may be quite resource consuming - even JITted hash computation is far behind optimized OpenSSL library code for instance.
- *It is not trivial to implement a proper authentication protocol*, so most developers rely on the well-known TLS layer for the security. Reinventing the wheel is not a good idea in a security context.
- *Security Auditors don't like custom protocols*. They prefer to have a known TLS, and check the WebServer settings, e.g. the TLS versions and enabled ciphers list. It is easy to verify, even if not fully secure.

On a corporate level, you may consider using a proven authentication algorithm like [Kerberos/Negotiate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26771225/458259), and a domain controller, then you will have a known client-side hashing with server-side and client-side challenge, and other benefits like single sign-on, and - most of all - centralized user management for authentication (even if authorization could be delegated at the web application level).

Security Auditors would easily recognize and validate it, and your manager would like the fact that the development cost is low, if the server is part of the domain controller. You may consider securing your most valuable resources using this authentication, and only allowing basic authentication for the main/insensitive parts of your website.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to jump in here with the express purpose of weighing in favor of the client-side hashing mechanism. Let's see how this benefits us:

Client-side:
No improvement.

In transit:
Protects the password in case of SSLstrip in which the password ends up being transmitted in cleartext. However, if HSTS is implemented, then most people would say that SSLStrip would have no effect. Right?
[No.](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Selvi-Bypassing-HTTP-Strict-Transport-Security-wp.pdf)

On entry to the server:
Finally, we see the major benefit. What happens if someone has compromised the server? They get a continuous flow of cleartext passwords if they just boot up Wireshark/TCPDump and export the server's private key. Now they can sit on the wire for a couple of months, and for high-volume servers (millions of user registrations per month), they get their massive plaintext breach. This is assuming that it is more valuable to grab the passwords for the people on the service than to have RCE on their server, of course.

On the server:
Performance benefits if it doesn't have to run bcrypt on every incoming password, which offloads some computational cost onto the client without introducing any new vulnerabilities. This seems to be a good thing for your server's administrator as well as your hardware costs.

Still, it looks like best practice would be to incorporate password hashing into the client side unless it creates unbearable page load times for the users.

Answer (score -1):

I think client-side hash has one upside and one drawback:

pro : You hide the password in case of dns/phishing/whatever, which is useful for the user, since most people reuse passwords on several service. As other devs said, this does nothing for your own security.

cons : Your server does not get the password, which prevents stuff like warning the user about password strength. I know some will say this can/should be client-side, but when you have multiple clients, this can be nice to centralize server-side.

Comment: (I did not downvote, would be nice if people could explain downvotes.) Password advice should really be done client-side. I would recommend a library like [zxcvbn](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) which is available in many different languages and seems very goal-oriented and well-designed. That would also limit having to incorporate the advice in all clients' code separately.

Answer (score -3):

As others have mentioned, TLS already allows clients to securely send login credentials over to the server. However, client-side hashing additional benefits in other areas such as reducing the load of password hashing computation at the server-side as well. Nonetheless, this is still uncommon as

1. Good, slow-hashing algorithms (e.g, `argon2`, `bcrypt`, etc) have not been [*natively-implemented*](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/50914/25009) by browsers yet -- although it is getting some traction over here: https://github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/59.
2. Some clients, especially those using *older, slower, more low-end devices* might become [negatively impacted](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/43038/25009) by shifting the ***vast bulk*** of the load of password hashing away from the server and onto these clients as well.

---

Note -- my answer above is purposefully sparse on details for the sake of brevity. To clarify some concerns various readers may have, I'll provide an "example implementation/workflow" of client-side hashing below:

1. Website login page asks for a user's credentials (e.g, `username` and `password`). The user sends their `username` along with `slow-hash(GUID || username || password)`. Where,

   - `GUID` is just a 128+ bit public constant (e.g, a hidden field on the login page), which makes the combination `GUID || username` a [*globally-unique, per-user* constant](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/174552/why-do-salts-for-hashing-passwords-need-to-be-globally-unique-not-just-system-s/) as well.
   - The "output" of `slow-hash` ([computed by the client](https://github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/59)) is [long](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30663/25009) (i.e, 128+ bits...)
2. Server identifies the client (via `username`), and performs just one quick, simple hash over the client output like `SHA2(server-salt || client-output)`, which is what is ultimately used (and gets stored) for password verification purposes (for at least [128 bits or more](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30663/25009)).

Comment: In client-side hashing, the hash becomes the password. There’s no reason to use a slow-hashing algorithm client-side. When doing client-side hashing, the hash sent by the client over TLS should be hashed again on the server (with a salt but without needing a slow hashing algorithm).

Comment: If your suggestion in this answer is for the server to accept the plaintext *string* from the client and store it without any obfuscation as an authentication secret, then you are making a very bad suggestion. There is a very good reason why we have password hashing server-side (since the 1960s).

Comment: @A.Hersean There is no problem at all making the client hash the password *if it is salted and sufficiently long as well* (e.g, 128+ bits -- a *[rather trivial](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30663/25009)* requirement). After all -- how would it be possible to "even attack" a 128-bit+ output of a slow client password hash *without actually performing the slow hash itself*? Hint -- merely just iterating over all (or even half of the) 2^128+ possible client hash-outputs is ***infeasible*** and hence **not a valid approach!**

Comment: @schroeder I've edited #2 from my answer to specify "***vast bulk*** of the load of password hashing" to clarify that I'm not suggesting the server *do no hashing at all*. But, you must understand, of course, that if slow hashing (with a salt, of course) is the *client's* responsibility, meanwhile a *server* only performs just one  mere (salted, as well) SHA-2 over the client hash output -- then the *client* is effectively handling 99.99%+of the total password hashing load (at which point, you could almost just round it up to 100%). Does this address your concerns??

Comment: Not really. "We get to reduce the load on the server" is a dubious benefit when you admit that there are no browser-based hashing functions and some client-side devices can't handle the computational load anyway. What you are really saying is that we ***could*** distribute the load to the clients if everything client-side was different. I'd remove that focus entirely, leaving the answer of "no hashing functions" and "weak clients".

Comment: Right, so like I was saying, you're "off in the weeds". The question is "Why is client-side hashing of a password so uncommon?". Your idea of how to do client-side hashing is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @schroeder Fair enough, but I figured to include the "possibility" of distributing password hashing load over to clients as a potential, *future-looking* approach [*if* it actually becomes available](https://github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/59) (as, some websites may eventually deprecate and/or no longer support older browsers anyway + popular OS's are [increasing their system requirements anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/windows-11-requirements)).

Comment: @schroeder Granted, since I've never owned/operated a server, it's not clear to me to what extent the *server-side* "system-requirements" (or the such, for app hosting) have also been increasing as well (if they have)...

Comment: @schroeder the purpose of the sample workflow/implementation was simply just to clear any doubts/assumptions readers might make regarding the shorter, sparser (less detailed) answer above.

Comment: @A. Hersean It seems you were under the impression that I somehow intended the server to do "no hashing at all". Hopefully the commentary & sample workflow helped clear up any misunderstanding^^

Comment: @A.Hersean Come to think of it, perhaps even calling it *"client-side **key-stretching**"*, rather than just, "hashing", would have been a much more clear/precise usage of my terminology here (although, my "sample mechanism" would already likely illustrate it anyway!)

Answer (score -5):

i think the probability of being hacked in client-side is more higher than that in server-side. (Because there are some IT expert look after the server) . if your computer is already being hacked. the client-side 's algorithms which used for hashing your password also can be stolen by hacker . Aso soon as your algorithms is no longer a secret. i think,it become useless.

Comment: We generally frown on secret algorithm (See [Kerckhoffs's principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs's_principle) and security-through-obscurity. Password hashing certainly doesn't need to rely on this. At most we apply a key and hope that the attacker doesn't find even if they manage to steal the database.

Comment: The "server is more secure" argument makes little sense in this context. 1) The client knows the plaintext password, so a trojan can trivially steal it with a key-logger. 2) Password hashing only offers an advantage over plaintext passwords when the server gets hacked and the database gets stolen.

Comment: The way twitter works is that you follow people whose tweets you find interesting. No need to ask for permission.

Comment: A server with all its user data is a way more valuable target than one single user.